# reset key count in array

Tags: php, arrays, simpledom

I have an array that is like this:

```
Array{
    10 - 2011 Headlight Assembly Nissan Versa 
    11 - LH 07-11 INS QTLY O.E.M - FREE SAME DAY SHIPPING 
    12 - 000 
    13 - A0 
    14 - 40626A1 
    15 - $165 actual 
    16 - More Desc Stuff
}
```

that is produced from a simple dom result. There are multiple items within the list. What I would like to do is reset the key back to 10 after 17 is reached so that I can loop over all the results within the array and find the proper values without having to look for say keys 10, 14, 15 - and then keys 20, 24, 25, etc.

Not quite sure if I have explained it correctly, or how to accomplish it. Any guidance is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I can't tell if that is pseudo code for an array, of if that is a string you are starting with. If it is a array, are the 10, 11, 12 etc the keys? Or is it part of a string for the value?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Does key 18 not exist? What is going on that you want to skip keys 18,19?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking makes sense to anyone. The mentioned array is not a valid array in PHP so maybe start with dropping in the actual information you are working with and then explain the iteration part again? Are you trying to control the keys when pushing to the array or when looping the array?

Comment: Use `var_export($array)` to get valid PHP code you can paste into SO for us.

Comment: sorry, yes that's a key=>val combination that I posted

Answer (score 0):

Well, for the indexes to deny I suggest you tu use an array of these indexes. and to loop through this array from 10 to 16 and then come back to 10, I suggest you to do this

```
$indexes_to_deny = [14,15,16];
$index = 10;
while( condition to stop the loop )
{

    if($index%17===0)
      $index = 10;
    if(in_array($index,$indexes_to_deny))
    {
      $index++;
      continue; 
    }

    /*
        your code here 
        you can access the items inside the array with $array[$index]
    */ 

    $index++:
}
```

Comment: hmmmm, somethings not right. Still not resetting them

Comment: can you explain more ?

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to use array_slice to drop off the unnecessary items and then array_chuck the rest and finally just drop the rest at a break point.